# Merge записей с CASCADE ForeignKey

Tags: mysql

Допустим есть две записи в таблице **user**. Так как это одна из основных таблиц в системе, на которой завязанны множество других таблиц, триггеров и прочих связей через **user_id**
Как правильней обьединить две записи в этой таблице? Чтоб во всех связанных таблицах поменялся **user_id**?

Пример

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=80 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`, `name`) VALUES
    (76, 'USER-76'),
    (79, 'USER-79');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_contact` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type_enum` enum('PHONE','EMAIL','SKYPE') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`type_enum`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_user_contact_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `user_contact` (`user_id`, `type_enum`, `value`) VALUES
    (76, 'PHONE', '76767676'),
    (76, 'EMAIL', 'test76@gmail.com'),
    (79, 'PHONE', '79797979'),
    (79, 'SKYPE', 'skype-79');
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/866d5f/1

Тоесть я хочу подмержить все записи **79-го** пользователя в **76-го**
При возникновении конфликта, значения из копируемой записи игнорируются

В голову пришло только такое

```
SET @FROM_ID = 79;
SET @TO_ID = 76;

START TRANSACTION;
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
DELETE FROM `user` WHERE user_id=@TO_ID;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
UPDATE `user` SET user_id=@TO_ID WHERE user_id=@FROM_ID;
COMMIT;
```

Но это только в том случае когда нет конфликтов.

В результате должно получиться следующее

```
SELECT
  u.user_id,
  u.name,
  uc.type_enum,
  uc.value
FROM `user` u
  LEFT JOIN user_contact uc USING (user_id);

+---------+---------+-----------+-------------------+
| user_id |  name   | type_enum |      value        |
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------------+
|      76 | USER-76 | PHONE     | 76767676          |
|      76 | USER-76 | EMAIL     | test76@gmail.com  |
|      76 | USER-76 | SKYPE     | skype79           |
+---------+---------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Можно конечно сходить во все связанные таблицы, и с помощью PHP обновить записи там, но это нужно найти все связи и писать целую систему для этого. Может есть способ попроще?

Answer (score 0):

Так может просто айдюки прописать у связанных таблиц?

`update 'linked_table' set userID=firstUser where userID=secondUser`

И если при этом происходит какой-то эксепшен, то и фиг с ним. А по завершению, просто удаляете пользователя `secondUser`

Comment: Я такой вариант рассматривал. И описал его в самом конце вопроса)) ```SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME,
  COLUMN_NAME,
  CONSTRAINT_NAME,
  REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test' 
  AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'user';```

Comment: @Ninazu Так зачем во первых PHP ? Во второых, не понимаю, что значит ` и писать целую систему для этог`

Comment: Потому что если руками поприсывать все имена таблиц, то это во первых долго, у меня больше сотни таблиц в базе, а во вторых не универсально, так как может в будущем мне понадобиться смержить не пользователей а еще какую-то таблицу. Можно конечно вытащить все FK и пройтись по ним, но под этим я и подразумевал "систему")

Comment: @Ninazu, ну так вот, все таблицы Вы и узнали. Далее просто по ним бежите и делаете как я сказал? Другого варианта нету. Первичный ключ смержить не возможно.

Comment: А я все же надеялся.....

Comment: И это всё можно сделать хранимкой без PHP

Comment: Кстати чтение из **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** очень тяжело даётся. У мну база на пару терабайт, видимо оно что-то там аггрегирует. Ключи считает или еще что-то. Успел кофе попить а оно **SELECT** оттуда делает